# How do I fix the input allowed into an input box?

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio-2010, input

How do I fix the input allowed into an input box?

Basically I want the user to be only allowed to type in numberical values (no spaces or symbols) also I want the inputbox to appear in this structure

02:10:20

And I don't want the user to be able to delete the colons.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can without creating a custom input box. You can however quit simply create a control to check the input and if it's in the wrong format prompt another inputbox.

The other option would be to create a custom input box where you can use masked textboxes...

Comment: How would I create a custom inputbox?

Comment: you can create a form and use it as a input box? Here's a nice tutorial:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/103846-custom-inputbox/

Answer (score 0):

Is it a web app?

If yes try use this jquery plugin:
http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#your-id/class").mask("99:99:99");
});
```