# How to get rid of cancel button in inputbox

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to get rid off the cancel button in the input box and also how to limit the characters that you input in the inputbox?

Comment: what do you mean by rid ?

Comment: @K3rnel31: get rid of = remove or hide, I suppose.

Comment: do u want to make little icon that remove the context of the inputbox?

Comment: yeah what Neolisk said

Comment: I just want to remove the cancel button

Comment: You cannot limit the characters of an input box. Unlike textboxes, you cannot set the maxlength propery.

Comment: @Arman Oh that sucks well I got this game when you beat the Highscore an inputbox pop ups and ask your name if you cannot limit the characters then inputbox wont be viable do you have an idea for a new method?

Comment: @user2993018 Best to do Neolisk's approach, but I found my self creating new windows forms then drag-and-drop textbox and buttons there to look like a real input box. Then I set the maxlength property of the textbox. Then I would call, showDialog() to fulfill the task. --yun lang

Comment: You'd want to have a table layout panel there, to allow for flexible input box, which would resize itself based on the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to create your own custom dialog, and implement any validation you want there. Ideas:

- [How do I fix the input allowed into an input box?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14563936/897326)
- [Create your own Custom InputBox](http://vbnetworld.blogspot.ca/2011/04/create-your-own-custom-inputbox.html)
- [Your Own InputBox](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/103846-custom-inputbox/)

Comment: +1 for the 3rd link, precise and clear. Oh my mistake, I accidentally made this as an answer.